# Access VB Script That Rounds To Nearest .005

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, rounding

I'm using MS Access 1997 and I need a VB script that can round records to the nearest 5 thousandth (.005).

So for example,

10.012 would round to 10.010
6.014 would round 6.015
8.147 would round to 8.150

I haven't been able to find much that is applicable for 1997 version of MS Access and nothing that seems to round to nearest .005. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
Round(number / 0.005, 0) * 0.005
```

Note that Access uses Banker's Rounding, which may not give you the results you want.  Use [this custom function by Ken Getz](http://access.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0054.htm) to get traditional rounding, if your version of Access doesn't have some variant of the Rounding function that rounds traditionally.